# Proper way of differentiating image uses into the iOS app without using Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, filenames, retina-display

Here's my images (organized in a seperate folders).

[image]

I've following file structure to show tutorials to our app users. I've a doubt regarding using following images.

I'll show each image with `UIImageView`. There'll be three consecutive images.

For the following line of code: `[UIImage imageWithName:@"intro01.png"];`

- if its 4 or 4s - app will take intro@2x.png ?
- if its 5 or 5s - app will take intro@2x.png or intro~568h@2x.png ?
- if its 6 or 6+ - app will take intro@3x.png ?

What about 5 or 5s? As I've added ~568h to differentiate those files, I will need to add it while passing image name?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here? And also help to choose proper image accordingly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I were you what I would do is add an Asset Catalog, which can be found in iOS Resource Template when selecting a new file or it may already be located in your xcode project. After clicking on your asset catalog add a new "Image Set". From there you can drag and drop images as needed for @1x, @2x, @3x.

Here is the Apple documentation on it
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html

Do use without asset catalog for all your images you will need to use:

```
UIImage backgroundImage = null;

if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 480)
    backgroundImage = UIImage.FromFile (@"File/Default@2x.png");
else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 568)
    backgroundImage = UIImage.FromFile (@"File/Default-568h@2x.png");
else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 667)
    backgroundImage = UIImage.FromFile (@"File/Default-667h@2x.png");
else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 736)
    backgroundImage = UIImage.FromFile (@"File/Default-736h@3x.png");
else
//etc for each iPad resolution

View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(backgroundImage);
```

Comment: Thanks Ven, I'm aware of that stuff. But *I don't want to use Asset Catalog*, still it is possible to organized by my self? To make my self more transparent, I've edit title of this question.

Comment: May I recommend using [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12). I have never used it personally, but a developer I work with on freelance projects, uses it and tells me its pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Use [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/_index.html), it automates naming process (as well as many other things).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kean, I'm aware of that stuff. But *I don't want to use Asset Catalog*, still it is possible to organized by my self? To make my self more transparent, I've edit title of this question.

Comment: "But I don't want to use Asset Catalog" - you should :)